# Modifing output xml files in mirth connect

Tags: xml, hl7, mirth

I am using mirth connect to get xml files based on input HL7 messages.

I want to add my custom tags in output xml file.

How can i do that?

Comment: Could you provide samples and let us know your experience level with Mirth?

Comment: Yes samples would help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

in your outbound message template, you have to create the output xml template, you can import it,
then in your code use tmp['tag'] = "value" to add the values to the output message. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcjGE.jpg , here  there is a little example

Answer (score 0):

To add to dani's answer...

You need to have an outbound template.
In your transformers,  the outbound template is referenced with tmp[].

In the example below (taken from a working transformer),  I'm adding the attribute assessmentID to an XML node name contained in the variable stype

```
var actsubid = 'AAA';
var stype = 'THISNODE';
tmp[stype]['@assessmentID'] = actsubid;
```

This will give you the output

```
<THISNODE assessmentID='AAA'>
```

If you want to add a text value:

```
tmp[stype] = 'TEXTHERE';
```

This gives you

```
<THISNODE assessmentID='AAA'>TEXTHERE</THISNODE>
```

To add a child node:

```
tmp[stype]['CHILD'] = 'CHILDNODE';
```

This gives you something like

```
<THISNODE assessmentID='AAA'>TEXTHERE
<CHILD>CHILDNODE</CHILD>
</THISNODE>
```